# Like button moves and breaks design when "liked"

Tags: facebook, css, facebook-like

I'm developing the front-end of this site: http://oq.totaleclips.com , and developing it from: http://dev-jon.c2mx-hrd.appspot.com

I've moved the social buttons to make the UI more appealing and to lessen confusion of having actual social links and graphic representations in the call to action graphic.

However, when I like the page on facebook now, the facebook button breaks the formation of the row of social buttons, and puts the like button below the others.

I've been trying to restrict the span and generated form that Facebook forces in from like.php, but to no avail.

How can I prevent Facebook Like button from moving and changing the design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to guess there is an issue with the plugin. The width property doesn't seem to be acknowledged or used.  For the time being you can use something like this..

```
parent_element_identifier span {
  width: [original_width]px !important;
}
```

This isn't a *good* fix, but works for me at the moment.

Er..also good to give it a bit of buffer for large numeric amounts (depending on where you're starting at with your original width)

Comment: Yes, that does seem to do the trick. It'll do it for now! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not the best way of doing it, but this should work:

```
.fb-like { display:inline-block !important; }
```

Comment: That in fact does the opposite of what I want or expect - it moves the Facebook button below the rest of the social buttons from the outset of page load. I want the design to remain intact.

Comment: I'm seeing this from the page-load with .fb-like {display:block !important;} : http://dirtymitten.org/dirtyimages/stackoverflow-facebook-q-1.png , and what I want to see is http://dirtymitten.org/dirtyimages/stackoverflow-facebook-desired-look.png

Comment: Perhaps try setting the display to `inline` or `inline-block`?